# Querying abstract class in entity framework using raw SqlQuery

Tags: entity-framework, abstract-class

I'm trying to query abstract entity using SqlQuery() method (code first).

```
public abstract class UserComment
{
    ... [internals]
}

public class BlogComment : UserComment
{
    ... [internals]
}

var result = Context.Database.SqlQuery<UserComment>(
                 @"select * from [UserComments] where ... [internals]",
                 new SqlParameter("user_id", user.Id));
```

This gives me error:

```
   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   Parameter name: constructor
```

If I change abstract type to concrete..

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<BlogComment>
```

...everything works fine.

Is it possible to query abstract class using raw queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it but I expect the answer is no. You cannot create instance of abstract class and that is exactly what EF is trying to do when materializing result set of the raw query.

Comment: I would expect EF to materialize the result set into the different concrete classes (which inherit from the abstract class)